# python asycio RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to send many requests to a url (~50) concurrently.

```
from asyncio import Queue

import yaml
import asyncio

from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector


async def http_get(url, cookie):
    cookie = cookie.split('; ')
    cookie1 = cookie[0].split('=')
    cookie2 = cookie[1].split('=')
    cookies = {
        cookie1[0]: cookie1[1],
        cookie2[0]: cookie2[1]
    }

    async with ClientSession(cookies=cookies) as session:
        async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
            return await response.json()


class FetchUtil:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = yaml.safe_load(open('../config.yaml'))

    def fetch(self):
        asyncio.run(self.extract_objects())

    async def http_get_objects(self, object_type, limit, offset):
        path = '/path' + \
               '?query=&filter=%s&limit=%s&offset=%s' % (
                   object_type,
                   limit,
                   offset)
        return await self.http_get_domain(path)

    async def http_get_objects_limit(self, object_type, offset):
        result = await self.http_get_objects(
            object_type,
            self.config['object_limit'],
            offset
        )
        return result['result']

    async def http_get_domain(self, path):
        return await http_get(
            f'https://{self.config["domain"]}{path}',
            self.config['cookie']
        )

    async def call_objects(self, object_type, offset):
        result = await self.http_get_objects_limit(
            object_type,
            offset
        )
        return result

    async def extract_objects(self):
        calls = []
        object_count = (await self.http_get_objects(
                'PV', '1', '0'))['result']['count']
        for i in range(0, object_count, self.config['object_limit']):
            calls.append(self.call_objects('PV', str(i)))

        queue = Queue()
        for i in range(0, len(calls), self.config['call_limit']):
            results = await asyncio.gather(*calls[i:self.config['call_limit']])
            await queue.put(results)
```

After running this code using fetch as the entry point i get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'FetchUtil.call_objects' was never awaited
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

The program that stops executing after `asyncio.gather` returns for the first time. I am having trouble understanding this message since I thought that I diligently made sure all functions were async tasks. The only function i didn't `await` was `call_objects` since i wanted it to run concurrently.

https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2017-07-31-common-mistakes-using-python3-asyncio.html#org630d301

in this article gives the following explanation:

> This runtime warning can happen in many scenarios, but the cause are
>   same: A coroutine object is created by the invocation of an async
>   function, but is never inserted into an EventLoop.

I believed that was what i was doing when i called the async tasks with asyncio.gather.

I should note that when i put a `print('url')` inside http_get it outputs the first 50 urls like i want, the problem seems to occur when asyncio.gather returns for the first time.

Comment: Perhaps `[i:self.config['call_limit']]` should be `[i:i + self.config['call_limit']]`? The former probably produces a bunch of empty slices, which results in some of the calls never getting passed to `gather` (and therefore never awaited).

Comment: You found a logical error which i fixed and then my program started working as intended, so thanks but i don't actually understand why it didn't just keep executing the same requests many time instead of stopping with an error.

Comment: I've now posted the explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code has a logic error: `[i:self.config['call_limit']]` should be `[i:i + self.config['call_limit']]`.

It causes the error because the expression evaluates to an entry slice in iterations after the first one, causing some of the calls coroutines to never get passed to `gather`, and therefore never awaited)

> i don't actually understand why it didn't just keep executing the same requests many time instead of stopping with an error.

Because your `i` would get incremented, making it larger than `call_limit` in every loop iteration except the first. For example, assuming `call_limit` is 10, `i` will be 0 in the first iteration, and you'll await `calls[0:10]`, so far so good. But in the next iteration, `i` will be 10, and you'll be awaiting `calls[10:10]`, an empty slice. In the iteration after that you'll await `calls[20:10]` (also an empty slice, although logically it should be an error), then `calls[30:10]`, again empty, and so on. Only the first iteration picks up actual members of the list.